# XSL test if indicated value doesn't exist within a loop and show result one time

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm new in xsl, ad I have trouble to get the result I want for an xml file. here is a part of my xml file which a query result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<SearchResults>
-<TableHeader>
<ColumnName>UCode</ColumnName>
<ColumnName>URev</ColumnName>
<ColumnName>Shapes</ColumnName>
<ColumnName>Name</ColumnName>
<ColumnName>Value</ColumnName>
</TableHeader>
-<Object>
<Attribute>XXXXXXX/Attribute>
<Attribute>A</Attribute>
<Attribute>BLABLA</Attribute>
<Attribute>PART_CODE</Attribute>
<Attribute>X123456</Attribute>
<Attribute/>
</Object>
-<Object>
<Attribute>YYYYYYYY/Attribute>
<Attribute>A</Attribute>
<Attribute>BLABLA</Attribute>
<Attribute>OPACITY</Attribute>
<Attribute>BLACK</Attribute>
<Attribute/>
</Object>
-<Object>
<Attribute>ZZZZZZZZ/Attribute>
<Attribute>A</Attribute>
<Attribute>BLABLA</Attribute>
<Attribute>PART_CODE</Attribute>
<Attribute>X198706</Attribute>
<Attribute/>
</Object>
-<Object>
<Attribute>XXXXXXX/Attribute>
<Attribute>A</Attribute>
<Attribute>BLABLA</Attribute>
<Attribute>OPACITY</Attribute>
<Attribute>BLACK</Attribute>
<Attribute/>
</Object>
</SearchResults>
```

Here is the part on my XSL thats shows a tag EXIST~YES only one time when I have Name='OPACITY' and Value='BLACK':

```
<xsl:for-each select="/queryResult/result/child::row">  
    <xsl:variable name="attnamez" select='Name'/>
        <xsl:if test="$attnamez='OPACITY'">
            <xsl:variable name="attvaluez" select='Value'/>
            <xsl:if test="$attvaluez!='NotDefined'">
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$attvaluez='BLACK'">

                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="count(preceding::row[Name='OPACITY' and Value=$attvaluez])=0">
                        &#x0A;EXIST~YES
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>

</xsl:for-each>
```

I need your help to diplay the tag EXIST~NO in case [Name='OPACITY' and Value='BLACK'] doesn't exist in all rows. actually, when I use "otherwise" block inside the for-each, it displays EXIST~NO several time (each time the value is not equal to BLACK).

many thanks for your help,

here is the xml generated:

```
 <queryResult>
 <result>
<row idx="1">
  <UCode>XXXXX</UCode> 
  <URev>B</URev> 
  <Name>OPACITY</Name> 
  <Value>WHITE</Value> 
  <SiteLegacy /> 
 </row>
<row idx="2">
  <UCode>YYYYYY</UCode> 
  <URev>B</URev> 
  <Name>OPACITY</Name> 
  <Value>BLACK</Value> 
  <SiteLegacy /> 
</row>
<row idx="3">
  <UCode>YYYYYY</UCode> 
  <URev>B</URev> 
  <Name>OPACITY</Name> 
  <Value>BLACK</Value> 
  <SiteLegacy /> 
</row>
<row idx="4">
  <UCode>YYYYYY</UCode> 
  <URev>B</URev> 
  <Name>OPACITY</Name> 
  <Value>BLACK</Value> 
  <SiteLegacy /> 
</row>
<row idx="5">
  <UCode>YYYYYY</UCode> 
  <URev>B</URev> 
  <Name>OPACITY</Name> 
  <Value>BLACK</Value> 
  <SiteLegacy /> 
</row>
  </result>
  </queryResult>
```

Comment: Your XSLT doesn't quite correspond to your XML. You XSLT is looking for `result` and `row` elements, but in your XML you seem to have `SearchResults` and `Object` elements.

Comment: Actually, I've done an export as XML of my query result. the xsl is executed when I execute a query (QML query). hence the loop using "/queryResult/result/child::row" and checking values row by row. do you have any idea on how can display the EXIST~NO one time in case the value BLACK doesn't exist in all rows? thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: We really need to see a sample of the actual XML that is input to the XSLT; the one with the `row` elements in. Thank you!

Comment: I've added the xml generated at the end of my first post since it contains several lines. please be aware that the result could be more than 5 rows. many thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer to take into account the relevant XML.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your XML, if you wanted to output "EXIST~YES" if there was at least one `row` with Name='OPACITY' and Value='BLACK', or "EXIST~NO" otherwise, you can simply do this...

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="queryResult/result/row[Name='OPACITY' and Value='BLACdK']">EXIST~YES</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>EXIST~NO</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

No need for `xsl:for-each` at all.

See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWk/1

Comment: Actually, I've done an export of the search result with xml format. However, the xsl is based on a query result (QML query). when I execute the query, the system executes the xsl code. hence using this way of looping the query result: <xsl:for-each select="/queryResult/result/child::row">.   using test="Object[Attribute='OPACITY' and Attribute='BLACK']" didn't work for me. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Thank you. it works when we put it inside the template where match="/" . However, I have already the same template where I call for the other templates: <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="queryResult/result[row]">
     <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>Not defined</xsl:otherwise> 
 </xsl:choose>

 <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>   .  is there a way to put the treatment in an existing template with match="Name"?

Comment: Change the test to `<xsl:when test="/queryResult/result/row[Name='OPACITY' and Value='BLACdK']">EXIST~YES</xsl:when>`. Then, it will work regardless of what template you are in.